# css for pop-out menu working different in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, menu

I am having trouble with a pop-out menu behaving different in Chrome than in IE or Firefox.

Here is the HTML

```
  <body>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="url">Level One</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="url">Level Two Item One</a></li>
             <li><a href="url">Level Two Item Two</a>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="url">Level Three</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
   </body>
```

Here is the css

```
 ul {
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
 }

 li {
 background-color: blue;
 }

 a:link {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #0000ff;
 margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
 background-color: cyan;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 }

 li {
 position: relative;
 }

 li > ul {
 display: none;
 }

 li:hover > ul, li.sfhover > ul {
 left 100%;
 top 0;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 }

 li:hover > ul li, li.sfhover > ul li {
 background-color: #33ff33;
 width: 200px;
 position: relative;
 }
```

In Firefox and IE Level Three pops out to the right of Level Two Item Two.  In Chrome Level Three pops out below Level Two Item Two.

I know it has something to do with making the link a block element, but I want the link to display as an inline-block.  Also, I cannot change the HTML.  It is coming from a CMS (I have simplified it to illustrate the problem)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You've got a couple of colons missing from your CSS, specifically this rule: `li:hover > ul, li.sfhover > ul `

Comment: I can't see where the colons are missing.

Comment: `left 100%; ` should be `left:100%;` and `top 0;` should be `top:0;`. I'm not sure it will fix your problem, but it should help to avoid any syntax based errors.

Comment: thanks - I'll fiddle a little more

Comment: Thanks David - I see that I can't use left: 100%  I was hoping I could find something that would place the item to the right of the previous item without using left: 200px

Comment: Can you make a working JSfiddle of the problem? I notice some of the class names referenced in your CSS are missing from the HTML, I think these are relevant.

Comment: Actually left: 100% works perfect with my original code. (not the scaled down version I have here)  Thanks a million David.  I guess I had just been staring at it so long that I became oblivious to the error.

Comment: No problem, I've added as an answer, please accept if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of colons missing from your CSS, specifically this rule: `li:hover > ul, li.sfhover > ul`

`left 100%;` should be`left:100%;` and `top 0;` should be `top:0;`

Comment: left: 100% works perfect with my original code (not the scaled down version here) Thanks a million David.  I guess I had just been staring at it so long that I became oblivious to the error.